# SQL - Create fixed-length string from INT(127 -> A000127)

Tags: t-sql

I have an INT column. I want to create a new column that is fixed-length(7)/varchar using the integer from the other column.

How  do I create the new column using a SELECT statement?

Thank you in advance!

[image: old column 127]

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: [Sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852/) is better presented as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have a management studio available to check the syntax, but 
it should be something like this:

```
SELECT existing, [new] = CONCAT('A', RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', CAST(existing AS VARCHAR(6)), 6))
FROM tableName;

-- if you have table and want to add a column containing that data:
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD COLUMN [new] CHAR(7) NULL; -- should create new column
UPDATE tableName SET New = CONCAT('A', RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', CAST(existing AS VARCHAR(6)), 6))
```

The principle is:

- convert the number to a text like '127'
- append to the left 6 '0' ('000000' + '127')
- take from that string '000000127' the rightest 6 characters ('000127')
- append the 'A' to the left: 'A000127'

Comment: Your second code snippet is wrong. the `new` column should be of type `char(7)`. Other then that, good answer.

Answer (score 0):

For most SQL databases you can use a combination of the LPAD and the CONCAT functions. The LPAD adds the zero's, the CONCAT prepends the letter 'A'.

```
update testtable set new=CONCAT('A',LPAD(existing, 6, '0'));
```

Comment: TSQL does not have an `LPAD` function.

Comment: Right but that tag wasn't there when I answered this question (or I missed it).